# Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Connection::table() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel

I would like to fetch data from the database that my application does not set as default.

```
        $second = \DB::connection('second_db');
        $john = $second_::table('fruits')->where('user_id', 5)->first();
```

ErrorException
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Connection::table() should not be called statically

happnes.

someone said "Create an instance"
I tried this

```
        $second = new \DB::connection('second_db');
        $record = $second::table('fruits')->where('user_id', 5)->first();
```

then, it happens below error.

syntax error, unexpected 'connection' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$john = \DB::connection('second_db')->table('fruits')->where('user_id', 5)->first();
```